# IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, android-audio-record

Ловлю

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

при попытке записи аудиофайла

```
int RECORDER_BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(AUDIO_RATE, CHANNEL, FORMAT) * BUFFER_SCALE;
int AUDIO_RATE = 11025;
int CHANNEL = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
int FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

byte[] buffer = new byte[RECORDER_BUFFER_SIZE];

recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, AUDIO_RATE, CHANNEL, FORMAT, RECORDER_BUFFER_SIZE * DELAY);

//start  record voice
recorder.startRecording();
```

Данную ошибку ловлю на устройстве Nexus 5 ( прошивка 6.0.1 ) ,  а на Nexus 4 и Nexus 7 с прошивками (5.0.1)  все работает нормально!

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28539778/3212712) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5440517/3212712)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло(